# PHP PDO is not displaying any data on my web page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've recently tried to convert my procedural MySQL queries to PDO statements. I've copied the following code from php official documentation and added my parameters to it. It is not showing any results in the page.

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn , $user, $pass);
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "An error has occurred. Please contact support. <br/>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$value = 'user1';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where username = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($value))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
}

?>
```

Comment: And no errors either?

Comment: where is closing right bracket for `while` statement?

Comment: No errors. And I've corrected the closing while bracket. But it is still the same.

Comment: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 <-- this is my result of echo phpversion(); do I have to install PDO or does it come with this version of PHP by default?

Comment: Ensure that `display_error` is set to `on` on your php.ini, maybe an error occurred but is not displayed.

Comment: i'm in linux. which php.ini do I change? /etc/apache2/php.ini? over there display error- default value: on, development value: on, production value: off

Comment: @MiniGunnR PLEASE MARK AND UP-VOTE THE ANSWER FOR OTHERS HELP. THANKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Try this:-

    <?php

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename';

    $user = 'user';

    $pass = 'password';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn , $user, $pass);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        print "An error has occurred. Please contact support. <br/>" .

     $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";

        die();

    }

    $value = 'user1';

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where column= ?");
   if ($stmt->execute(array($value))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: where is execute? without execute there'll be no result from db

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks man. But what is the correct way to close the connection if I want to? Also, now my previous version of prepared statement works too. Something wrong with closing the connection. :)

Comment: related to closing connection please check the marked answer in this link:-stackoverflow.com/questions/18277233/pdo-closing-connection